# How can I access the IP address of the display generated by ESP32-CAM

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ip, esp32

I want to use the display generated by EPS32-CAM in my Android application (in java or kotlin). For this, I communicate ESP32 with the mobile device via a WI-FI hotspot. Then I enter the IP address from the serial monitor in Arduino and access the display. Instead of doing this process, I want it to connect directly. How can I do it?